# Why Does College Scorecard institution-level earning data stop are 2014-15 data file?

Tags: collegescorecard

From examining the College Scorecard data, it appears that median and mean earnings data stop being reported after the 2014-15 data and the values are null for the 2015-16 through 2018-19 data files. Is this reported elsewhere? And does anyone know why it is no longer included in the Scorecard data?

I know program-level data were released in 2019, but these neither appear to include institution-level values nor can one create institution-level values because so many of the program-level values are privacy suppressed.